# Xcode Crashes abruptly when a Account is added

Tags: macos, xcode7.2

Hello All,
                   I installed Xcode 7.2.1 application on El Capitan and whenever I try to  add an account it crashes. However I don’t observe same issue on other MAC. I am still trying to find a solution but I was wondering  if anyone can help me with this issue. Below are the reproducible steps  :
1)  Launch Xcode. Click on Xcode from menu bar and select preferences.
2)  This launches a window and select Accounts tab.
3)  You will see “+” @ bottom left hand side of the window. Select Add Apple ID option
4)  When I enter  the credentials it crashes. FYI:  Irrespective of developer credentials result is the same.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do a Data BAck Up-->Delete the account--> Re add the account. Update the Xcode if required.